# Can someone explain to me why this code give me a Seg Fault.?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Can someone explain to me why this code give me a seg Fault.?

```
char  cmd[MAXSIZE];
char* args[2];
fgets(cmd, MAXSIZE, stdin);
// read_line(cmd);
char* cmdPt = cmd;
printf(cmdPt[0]);
```

And then when I:

```
printf("%c", cmdPt[0])
```

It doesn't give my seg Fault.

Comment: What's the **type** of `cmdPt[0]`? What's the type of the first parameter `printf` expects?

Comment: don't use printf() without a format string! Think about what happens If the string you are printing contains format specifiers....

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `printf()` statement.

`printf(cmdPt[0]);` should be `printf(cmdPt);`
Because `printf()` first argument is `const char *format` i.e you should provide *char array base address* not single char.

Read the compiler warnings properly, you can find yourself solution.

> expected ‘const char * **restrict**’ but argument is of type ‘char’

Better you should use `printf()` with a format string. As suggested in comments, you should always compile your code with flags `-Wall -pedantic-errors` It helps you lot.

Comment: Better yet, compile with `-pedantic-errors` and those conformance warnings will become errors.

Comment: I didn't get @StoryTeller. Do you want to say that if I will compile with `-pedantic-errors` option, warnings become error ? I understood, Doesn't  `-Wall` is enough to indicate warnings.

Comment: That warning is one of many that indicate the program violates ISO C constraints. But warnings can be ignored (if they even show up by default). To get strict conformance, I like to add the `-pedantic-errors` flag. It's less than `-Werror` (which is a bit too restrictive IMO).

Comment: @StoryTeller: If behaving disciplined `-pedantic` would just do.

Comment: Its very useful information for me. thanks @StoryTeller . yes only `-pedantic` gives the warning about violations of ISO C constraints.

Comment: @alk - You or I will fix those warnings. A learner (like the OP is) won't. It's better to start of with those as errors, to pick up good habits easily.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Fair enough. My favourite options are: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`. The latter is more to double-check my personal sloppiness in mixing types. I fix the code it warns about on a case by case base only. I do not use it in Production builds.

Comment: Thanks, That answered my question.